# SWT - How do you re-size/set size of an a Composite residing inside another composite?

Tags: java, swt, windowbuilder

//I have a composite within a scrolled composite.

```
final Composite c = new Composite(scrolledComposite, SWT.NONE); //1
c.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
c.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
```

//I have a for loop that adds composites to composite c

```
for(int i = 0; i<100; i++){ 

    Composite b = new Composite(c, SWT.BORDER);
    b.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_LIST_SELECTION));
    b.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));
    b.setBounds(112, 70, 268, 69);
```

//and then some controllers added to that inner composite

```
    Label lblNewLabel_2 = new Label(b, SWT.NONE);
    lblNewLabel_2.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1, 4));
    Image img = new Image(Display.getCurrent(), result.get(i).getPicturePath());


//.... more controllers.
```

// finally I end the loop and add the outer most composite to an scrolled composite.

```
} // end loop           
    scrolledComposite.setContent(c); //setter content!
    scrolledComposite.setMinSize(c.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));
```

This all works great, almost. My problem is that the inner composite wont respond to the setBounds method. No matter what I'm writing in it I cant get it to expand. I suspect this have something to do with the layouts.

Anyone got a clue?

Thanks in advance.

Petter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Layouts are the objects that set size and location of composite's children so you wouldn't have to call `setBounds()` for every one of them. Check out [Understanding Layouts in SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html).

[What is the purpose of Layout in SWT applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388184/what-is-the-purpose-of-layout-in-swt-applications)

Answer (score 0):

Consider a Resize listener in your outer panel to have it adjust your inner panel.

```
_outerPanel.addListener(SWT.Resize, new Listener() {
    public void handleEvent(Event e) {
        computePanelSize();  // computes the inner panel size
    }
});
```