# ViewPart comes up blank

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I have a view, this view is initialized but when it could comes up totally blank.

As I haven't worked with ViewParts that much are there any obvious things to look for?

I'm thinking of the equivalent of Java Swings . setVisible(true) of something like that. It's a pretty vague description but Googling it didn't give me that much information and the class I'm working with is not written from scratch.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you may have problem with your composite like one composite may be ovelapped by other blank composite. check that one through your structure.

Comment: We might need some code to help you. Maybe an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org)?

Comment: @Dinupkandel something like that is what I'm thinking, but it's not my area so I'm pretty lost! How can I check this? What are the things to look for?

Comment: @Baz an SSCCE sounds like a nice thing, but how in the name of highschool football do I produce(?) one? The thing is that the class is several hundred rows of code that use to work but for some reason stopped working

Comment: @marko Yes, creating an SSCCE is an art. But when creating one you will most probably find the mistake on your own.

Comment: @marko could just post some beginnig of you code. i will take a look on it.

Comment: A very common error is that your Composites does not have a proper Layout...

Answer (score 1):

this is just the beginning the code try this one.

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.ui.part.ViewPart;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;

public class test extends ViewPart {

    public test() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    @Override
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Composite comParent = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);      
        Button button = new Button(comParent, SWT.NONE);
        button.setBounds(97, 97, 75, 25);
        button.setText("New Button");   
    }
    @Override
    public void setFocus() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: You really should not use absolute positioning/sizing of controls! Use layouts... [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388184/what-is-the-purpose-of-layout-in-swt-applications) are some very good reasons for using layouts.

Comment: @Baz you are absolutely right i was just solving him for viewing problem.

Comment: I see. Then maybe add a note to your answer.

Comment: Hi! @Dinupkandel that code worked fine, I saw a button as expected. I'll try to debug the current code and see if I can find something fishy! Any suggestions now?

Comment: @marko well try to use grid layout or something like that for proper position of controls in you button. if somehting goes wrong then i am ready to help you.